# Databases in uppercase and lowercase on same mysql instance

Tags: mysql, linux, database-schema, uppercase, lowercase

I have two database schema, one with tables in uppercase, the other with table in lowercase :

```
mysql uppercase_schema -e 'show tables'
+-----------------+
| UPPERCASE_TABLE |
+-----------------+
mysql lowercase_schema -e 'show tables'
+-----------------+
| lowercase_table |
+-----------------+
```

I need to access both on the same mysql instance. The problem: lowercase_table is queried in a mixed of uppercase and lowercase (no way to change the query) :

```
select * from LowerCASE_table;
```

I was wondering how to go about using mysql options such as `lower_case_table_names` without dumping UPPERCASE_TABLE.

Comment: On what filesystem is your database stored?

Comment: @eggyal: ext3 filesystem